# Select filled rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range with fixed columns and rows from (A1 to C15)  (not a table)

I want to select the rows which column 1 is filled (numbering). is it makable by VBA?

[image: 1]

thanks in advance

select filled rows based on cell

Answer (score 0):

- In most case, you don't need `Select` with VBA code

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim lastRow As Long, oSht As Worksheet
    Set oSht = ActiveSheet ' modify as needed
    With oSht.Range("A15")
        If Len(.Value) > 0 Then
            lastRow = 15
        Else
            lastRow = .End(xlUp).Row
        End If
    End With
    ' Select the first 3 Cols
    oSht.Range("A2:C" & lastRow).Select
    ' Select rows
    ' oSht.Range("2:" & lastRow).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Can i limit this to A 15? as in A16 there is a text that is being selected.

Comment: So it select the filled rows based on Col A till Row 15 only

Answer (score 0):

try the below

```
Dim LR1 As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' adjust to your sheet name
LR1 = sht.Cells(sht.rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

If LR1 > 15 Then LR1 = 15
Range("A2", "C" & LR1).Select
```

Comment: Can i limit this to A 15? as in A16 there is a text that is being selected. So it select the filled rows based on Col A till Row 15 only.

Comment: Yes you can. Simply add "If LR1 > 15 Then LR1 = 15" before the line "Range("A2", "C" & LR1).Select" - I hope this helps.